# How to highlight all terms in ElasticSearch or Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch, search-engine, information-retrieval

I'm not sure if ElasticSearch or Solr can handle this, but it sounds a search engine related application. The requirement is:

Giving a company name (100k) list and millions of documents, highlight all company names in search result.

It's not like a typical search engine application, e.g. user inputs a keyword and search engine returns all hits and highlight it. I'm looking into APIs and trying to figure out how to do it. Anybody has any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use a GET param with the search keyword + CSS fallback to highlight the term into

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean merge all 100K company names into one search keyword? Could you please elaborate it? Thanks.